# How to specify default style in Mathematica 9

Tags: front-end

In *Mathematica* 8, I can use `GraphicsBoxOptions->{DefaultBaseStyle->{"Graphics", FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 14}}` to specify the default font for graphics. But this does not work for *Mathematica* 9. How to specify the default style in *Mathematica* 9 then?

Using `BaseStyle` may be a solution. But it is not generalizable to other default styles like `DefaultAxesStyle`, `DefaultFrameStyle` etc. Originally `DefaultAxesStyle->{"GraphicsAxes", FontSize -> 12}` works in *Mathematica* 8, but it runs into error in *Mathematica* 9 (message: `The specified setting for the option GraphicsBoxOptions, DefaultAxesStyle cannot be used`). Does anyone know about the style specification grammar in *Mathematica* 9?

Answer (score 11):

You can set all sorts of options to `Graphics` using the `SetOptions` command:

```
SetOptions[Graphics, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

The output from this command will show you some other options that you can set. Here I've just set the font style and axes style; `FrameStyle` can be added as you wish.

```
(*{AlignmentPoint -> Center, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> None, AxesOrigin -> Automatic, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Thickness[Large]], 
 Background -> None, BaselinePosition -> Automatic, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16}, 
 ColorOutput -> Automatic, ContentSelectable -> Automatic, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> Automatic, 
 DisplayFunction :> $DisplayFunction, Epilog -> {}, 
 FormatType :> ( ##1 &), Frame -> False, FrameLabel -> None, 
 FrameStyle -> {}, FrameTicks -> Automatic, FrameTicksStyle -> {}, 
 GridLines -> None, GridLinesStyle -> {}, ImageMargins -> 0., 
 ImagePadding -> All, ImageSize -> Automatic, 
 ImageSizeRaw -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> {}, Method -> Automatic, 
 PlotLabel -> None, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Automatic, PlotRegion -> Automatic, 
 PreserveImageOptions -> Automatic, Prolog -> {}, RotateLabel -> True,
  Ticks -> Automatic, TicksStyle -> {}} *)
```

This shows that it works:

```
Graphics[Text["this is a test", {0.5, 0.5}], Axes -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 150]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It solve part of the problem. I also want to modify DefaultAxesStyle and DefaultFrameStyle etc. Do you know how to write the style specification in Mathematica 9?

Comment: Does this work for all things such as `Plot` that produce `GraphicsBox` FE objects or only `Graphics` created directly?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This only works for `Graphics` created directly.  Mike Honeychurch has a great answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36770/12).