# How can I prevent kets to from growing too large?

Tags: formatting, traditional-form

In `TraditionalForm`, *Mathematica* formats kets incorrectly in certain expressions.

For example, if used in a summation with indices indicated, a ket becomes too "tall" (red) compared to the rest of the expression:

[image: see the big ket]

Is there a way to prevent this gigantism?

---

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{
   RowBox[{
    RowBox[{
     RowBox[{
      RowBox[{
       RowBox[{
        RowBox[{
         RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", "\[Psi]"}], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}], "=", 
        RowBox[{
         SubscriptBox["\[Delta]", "0"], 
         RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", 
          SubscriptBox["d", "0"]}]}]}], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}], "+", "\[Ellipsis]", "+", 
      RowBox[{
       SubscriptBox["\[Delta]", 
        RowBox[{"N", "-", "1"}]], 
       RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", 
        SubscriptBox["d", 
         RowBox[{"N", "-", "1"}]]}]}]}], "\[RightAngleBracket]"}], "=", 
    RowBox[{
     UnderoverscriptBox["\[Sum]", 
      RowBox[{"i", "=", "0"}], 
      RowBox[{"N", "-", "1"}]], 
     RowBox[{
      SubscriptBox["\[Delta]", "i"], 
      RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", 
       SubscriptBox["d", "i"]}]}]}]}], 
   StyleBox["\[RightAngleBracket]",
    FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]}], TraditionalForm]], "DisplayFormula"]
```

Comment: Would you please post code for that expression?

Comment: When my kets started getting big, way back when, I simply stopped feeding them. They still haven't forgotten.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To prevent this from happening, you may be able to make use of the new-in-8 keyboard shortcut <kbd>Esc</kbd>`ket`<kbd>Esc</kbd>, and similarly for the other symbols, <kbd>Esc</kbd>`bra`<kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>`braket`<kbd>Esc</kbd>. These shortcuts bring up a template which is already delimited appropriately. After entering this, you have to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get "teleported" into the placeholder where the contents of the ket is entered:

[image: picture of the ket as it appears in the notebook]

This approach works equally well in `TraditionalForm` or in normal `Input` cells, since it relies on the new (but undocumented) symbols `Bra`, `Ket`, and `BraKet` for its display form.

Comment: That was the problem. I was using the characters from the palette to build a ket "from scratch". I didn't know that there was built-in support.

Comment: Thanks - there is a hole in the docs for this. If you say `?Ket` you get nothing.

Comment: @Jens When I run Options[$FrontEnd, InputAliases], "ket", "bra" and "braket" are not in the list. I am not sure if it is because you have loaded some package before that defines them, but they are not built-in alias for Mathematica. I like you idea anyway. So I have provided the code to define these alias in my answer.

Comment: @EverettYou Jens' answer works perfectly fine here on mma9 and I haven't loaded anything.

Comment: @EverettYou these aliases are new in *Mathematica* 8. While it might be a good idea to edit the answer to point this out (as I have just done), personally I wouldn't downvote. (That said, I don't think it's reasonable to downvote your answer either, since it is quite valid if you use version 7 or below.) Of course, people are absolutely entitled to cast their votes as they see fit, but it's worth remembering that not everyone is necessarily able to test their answers in all relatively recent versions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: @EverettYou let me make a suggestion. Before you take such an aggressive stance, like "the answer simply does not work so I'm downvoting you", try providing extra information, such as version and os. That way, we can diagnose _why_ it doesn't work, and make corrections as necessary. In particular, I wonder what OS you're running because I [_know_](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17932/52) you have access to v9.

Comment: Sorry everyone, and sorry to the author. I am regretful that I had down-vote this nice answer in an angry mood. I have corrected this mistake by an up-vote of this answer. I am using v9 on Mac, but could not figure out why the alias not working. I guess my code could be useful for those who is suffering from the same problem, and definitely for those with v7 or older versions.

Answer (score 13):

Your are in computational mode, when Mathematica cares that you do not have any corresponding bra. It seems to me that you do not really care for computation and a reasonable thing would be to got to a typesetting realm. Then what about entering things as strings?

[image]

I used palettes to type it, but the code for this is:

```
TraditionalForm["\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(N \
- 1\)]\)\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Delta]\), \(i\)]\)|\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(d\), \(i\)]\)\[RightAngleBracket]"]
```

Comment: Ket? *Bra?*  That's some [weird science.](http://cdn.hark.com/images/000/854/212/854212/but-gary-dot_clink_large.jpg)

Comment: I made it red to highlight it.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius this is why posting code would be useful. I corrected text.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So true - I currently teach quantum mechanics, and this bra business does causes an awkward moment when you start talking about it. Maybe especially now because the field is slowly becoming more gender diverse. We should go back to teaching this stuff in German, that would solve the problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes! It's a complete weird science! And very beautiful too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Jens's answer provides a good idea, but for some users (with v7 or older versions), "ket", "bra" and "braket" are not built-in *Mathematica* input aliases. To define these aliases in *Mathematica*, one may execute the following code:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, 
 InputAliases -> 
  Join[{"ket" -> 
     TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]"}, "Ket", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{"\[LeftBracketingBar]", #1, 
           "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] &)], 
    "bra" -> 
     TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]"}, "Bra", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", #1, 
           "\[RightBracketingBar]"}] &)], 
    "braket" -> 
     TemplateBox[{"\[Placeholder]", "\[Placeholder]"}, "BraKet", 
      DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{"\[LeftAngleBracket]", #1, "|", #2, 
           "\[RightAngleBracket]"}] &)]}, 
   OptionValue[Options[$FrontEnd], InputAliases]]]
```

Then you can use <kbd>Esc</kbd> ket <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter the ket. The `TemplateBox` is used to delimit the template. One may change the `DisplayFunction` to specify the desired box appearance.

Comment: So you downvoted my "good idea" even though it's the accepted answer? What's the logic in that? If the alias doesn't work for you in particular, maybe you should first ask a question to clarify why it doesn't.

Comment: @Jens If you had provide the definition of these non-standard alias, that would be a wonderful answer. I was so annoyed to find that the alias not working. I am sorry to down-vote your answer in a bad mood. I am now willing to up-vote your answer if you could accommodate my code in your answer for those who did not have the alias predefined in their system.

Comment: On v9, enter `Options[EvaluationNotebook[], InputAliases]` and see what you get.

Comment: I'm using v9 and `[Esc]ket[Esc]` works perfectly.