# How to get and set default font parameters for Plot, ListPlot, LogPlot, etc.?

Tags: graphics, fonts

How can I find the *default* font parameters (family, size, etc.) for the text that appears in `Graphics` produced by `Plot`, `ListPlot`, `LogPlot`, etc.?

I'm interested not only in the font specs used for axis and plot labels, but also (and importantly) in those for the numbers displayed next to tick marks.

EDIT: At the moment there appears to be two entirely different ways to set these parameters, and it is not clear to me which one takes precedence.  One, suggested by [ybeltukov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4678/ybeltukov), is through `Format->EditStylesheet...`.  The other one, described in the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17932/5478) linked to by [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba), is through `SetOptions[Graphics, 
 BaseStyle -> {...}]`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Font family, size, etc. depends on "Graphics" style in the notebook stylesheet

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics", "FontSize"}]
 (* 10 *)

CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics", "FontFamily"}]
 (* "Times" *)
```

You can manually change it: open Format->Edit Stylesheet..., add

```
 Cell[StyleData["Graphics"],FontSize->20]
```

and press Ctrl+Shift+E. You will see that the font in `Plot`,`LinePlot`, etc. instantly increase.

*Edit:* default values for `Plot`, `ListPlot`, etc. separately can be set by

```
SetOptions[Plot, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSize -> 16}]
```

Comment: So I was wrong. Thanks, I wasn't paying attention to StyleDefinitions :) You can mention the `TraditionalForm` for Labels issue. Also, one have to be aware the `SetOptions` is sometimes tricky - [How can I...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/332/5478)

Comment: @Kuba What is Labels issue? Both methods (`SetOptions` and edit stylesheet) work for plot and axis labels.

Comment: That labels are by default in `TraditionalForm`. I know `SetOptions` will work here but just to point out it is not always work for other functions. I find your answer great, those are just details.

Comment: @Kuba Can you give an example? I've noticed that if I change TraditionalForm style, it overwrite Graphics style for plot and axes labels and numbers on axes. Moreover, there are GraphicsLabel style, which affects axes labels and numbers (not plot label!).

Comment: I was referring to [PlotLabel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotLabel.html?q=PlotLabel&lang=en) > Details.

Comment: none of these solutions change anything in the newer versions of Mathematica, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out quite by accident, and I will show you why, but the short answer to your question is to Find the length of the command and then display that. For example, consider the plot function.

```
 In[50]:= Length[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]

 Out[50]= 2
```

Now we can look at these two elements and you will see all:

You can see the hue (`Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6]`) of the classic blue line in

```
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}][[1]]
```

You can see all sorts of other hidden details in

```
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}][[2]]
```

For example, the default aspect ratio is `1/GoldenRatio`.

I will show you how I found this, why, and how I changed a function that I could not otherwise change. I was trying to make polyhedral nets, and the function

```
 PolyhedronData["Disphenocingulum", "NetImage"]
```

gives a net, but there is no way to change this baby barf yellow color. What I did was this. I computed and looked at

```
 PolyhedronData["Disphenocingulum", "NetImage"][[1]]
```

I saw that this ugly yellow was `RGBColor[1, 1, 0.85]`. I replaced the regular polyhedron data function with

```
 Graphics[
 ReplacePart[
 PolyhedronData["Disphenocingulum", "NetImage"][[1]], 
  1 -> FaceForm[RGBColor[1, 1, 1]]]]
```

Eureka, I made the background white and never gave it a second thought until today. I feel like I answered your question. As for me, I had no choice but to find these hidden details, as I could not figure out how to manipulate the built in function otherwise.

I think this method should show the hidden guts of pretty much every function you have in mind.

Comment: try `FullForm`, such as `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi}]//FullForm`

Comment: Hah! Dirk that is indeed a much faster way. I see all. Very good.

Comment: `InputForm` is very useful too for examining graphics expressions, it's easier to read than `FullForm`.