# Set Standard Plot Thickness

Tags: plotting, options, style

All of my plots should have the same set styling, that is, for instance, 
`{ImageSize->460, Frame->True, PlotStyle->Thickness[0.004]}`.

Of course I do not want to repeat these settings in every `Plot`.

`SetOptions[]` is a convenient way to set the standards for `ImageSize` and `Frame`. However, it fails for defining the thickness. Often I need to use extra plot styling options such as dashing of colour. In these cases the setting for the plot thickness is overwritten.

Is there an easy way to define the standard plot thickness such that is is not reset when I use a command `Plot[x,{x,0,4}, PlotStyle->Red]`?

The only way I found is to write a custom plot which intercepts the `OptionsPattern[]`, checks if `PlotStyle` and `Thickness` is defined and, if `Thickness` is not defined adds it to the `PlotStyle` list and runs `Plot[]`.

However, this is long process. And needs to account for single and multiple plots. Below  is an example for a single plot, that is, `Plot[x,{x,0,4}, PlotStyle->Red]` works  `Plot[{x,x^2},{x,0,4}, PlotStyle->{Red,Green}]` does not.

```
    AddItems[oldItems_, newItems_] := Module[{ii},
  out = oldItems;
  For[ii = 1, ii <= Length[newItems], ii++,
    out = 
     out /. Rule[newItems[[ii, 1]], _] :> 
       Rule[newItems[[ii, 1]], newItems[[ii, 2]]];
   ];
  Clear[ii];
  out = DeleteDuplicates[Join[out, newItems]]
  ]
MyPlot[a_, b_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{plotStyle, optsOut},
  plotStyle = PlotStyle /. {opts};
  If[plotStyle === PlotStyle,
    optsOut = AddItems[{opts}, {PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.004]}]
   ,
    plotStyle = Join[{Thickness[0.004]}, Flatten[{plotStyle}]];
    optsOut = AddItems[{opts}, {PlotStyle -> plotStyle}];
   ];
  Print[optsOut];
  Plot[a, b, Evaluate[optsOut]]
  ]
```

EDIT: Thanks kuba, using `BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.004]` solves it. Was looking for that for so long.

Comment: closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31735/5478