# Set PlotTheme globally without overriding custom (font) settings

Tags: plotting, style

Content of the *initialization cell*:

```
SetOptions[ListPlot
, Frame -> True
, GridLines -> Automatic
, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", FontSize -> 16}
, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 0.001}
];
```

Result, without setting `PlotTheme`:

[image: ListPlot without PlotTheme]

Result with `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` added to the ListPlot settings in the initiliazation cell:

[image: ListPlot with PlotTheme]

As one can easily see, the FontFamily settings were overwritten by the "Monochrome" `PlotTheme`.
How can I set the monochrome color and plot marker style without overriding my custom plot settings?

Bonus question: How can I globally set (reduce) the `PlotMarker` size, because the "Monochrome" theme uses a relatively large one by default.

Comment: Before someone closes this for being a possible duplicate, [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31735/how-to-get-and-set-default-font-parameters-for-plot-listplot-logplot-etc) does not solve my question