# Change base font for all graphics objects

Tags: graphics, formatting, customization, default

How can I change the base font style for *all* graphics objects, including the ones generated using plotting functions?

I would like to change this *a single time* and have it affect all graphics generated from there on (i.e. not specify the font on a plot by plot basis).

Say, I'd like to use 16 point Helvetica for everything by default.

---

My original thought was `SetOptions[Graphics, BaseStyle -> {...}]`, but this will be overridden on graphics created using the various plotting functions (e.g. `Plot`).

My second try was changing the `BaseStyle` in the `GraphicsBoxOptions` of the notebook, but this didn't have an effect.

Comment: Related: [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10776/862) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17932/862)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To begin with your observation

```
SetOptions[Graphics, BaseStyle->{FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]
```

doesn't work with `Plot` -- which seems unintuitive.

[image]

The styling for graphics is controlled by the `Graphics` style in the core.nb stylesheet.

[image]

We see here that font type and size etc. is explicitly specified so this seems to be taking precedence. For example having a local `Graphics` style in a private stylesheet with

```
Cell[StyleData["Graphics"],
 GraphicsBoxOptions->{BaseStyle->Directive[FontFamily->"Helvetica",RGBColor[1,0,0],FontSize->16]}]
```

has no effect. This is analogous to evaluating `SetOptions` as above.

So if you want to change the base font for all graphics what you need to do is override those specified font styles in the core.nb stylesheet. For example add this to your private stylesheet or to the stylesheet you regularly use.

```
Cell[StyleData["Graphics"],
 FontFamily->"Helvetica",
 FontSize->16,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0]]
```

[image]

and you will see it has immediate effect (the pic below is the same cells as the screen grab above. No addition evaluation has taken place. After adding the new `Graphics` style the fonts automatically change):

[image]

Comment: Are `GraphicsBoxOptions` part of any stylesheet or is it FrontEnd option, I can't find it.

Comment: @Kuba they can be included as options to any style ...obviously the intended style would be expected to have graphics rendered in the cell

Comment: Yes yes, I mean, where are generic `GraphicsBoxOptions` for e.g. Output inherited from?

Comment: @kuba I do not know. there does not appear to be a parent anywhere

Comment: I always find working with stylesheets confusing. Any chance you could add some code that creates the appropriate private stylesheet and sets it as the stylesheet for that notebook?

Answer (score 5):

While Mike's answer is of course very nice and useful I'd like to add a very simple Kernel-only idea: Just put all the relevant `SetOptions` statements into your init.m startup file. 
This is easily done, once, e.g., like:

```
Export[
 FindFile[
  "init.m"], (StringJoin[
   "Map[SetOptions[#, BaseStyle \[Rule] {FontFamily->\"Helvetica\", \
FontColor->Red, FontSize->16}]&,\n{",
   ExportString[
    Riffle[#, ","] &@
     ToExpression@
      Quiet@Select[
        Select[Names[
          "System`*"], ! StringMatchQ[#, "*Box*" | "$*"] &], ! 
          FreeQ[Options[Symbol[#]][[All, 1]], BaseStyle] &], "List"], 
   "}];\n"]
  ), "Text", CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"]
```

This produces (check by FilePrint@FindFile["init.m"] ) :

```
Map[SetOptions[#, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily->"Helvetica", FontColor->Red, FontSize->16}]&,
{ActionMenu
,
AdjacencyGraph
,
AngularGauge
,
Animate
,
Animator
,
ArrayPlot
,
BarChart
,
BarChart3D
,
BodePlot
,
BooleanGraph
,
BubbleChart
,
BubbleChart3D
,
BulletGauge
,
ButterflyGraph
,
Button
,
ButtonBar
,
CancelButton
,
CandlestickChart
,
CayleyGraph
,
Checkbox
,
CheckboxBar
,
CirculantGraph
,
ClockGauge
,
ColorSetter
,
ColorSlider
,
Column
,
CommunityGraphPlot
,
CompleteGraph
,
CompleteKaryTree
,
ContourPlot
,
ContourPlot3D
,
ControllerManipulate
,
CycleGraph
,
DateListLogPlot
,
DateListPlot
,
DeBruijnGraph
,
DefaultButton
,
DensityHistogram
,
DensityPlot
,
DirectedGraph
,
DiscretePlot
,
DiscretePlot3D
,
DistributionChart
,
Dynamic
,
DynamicModule
,
DynamicNamespace
,
DynamicWrapper
,
FileNameSetter
,
FlipView
,
Framed
,
Graph
,
GraphComplement
,
GraphDifference
,
GraphDisjointUnion
,
Graphics
,
Graphics3D
,
GraphicsArray
,
GraphicsColumn
,
GraphicsGrid
,
GraphicsRow
,
GraphIntersection
,
GraphPlot
,
GraphPlot3D
,
GraphPower
,
GraphUnion
,
Grid
,
GridGraph
,
HararyGraph
,
HighlightGraph
,
Histogram
,
Histogram3D
,
HorizontalGauge
,
HypercubeGraph
,
Hyperlink
,
ImageHistogram
,
IncidenceGraph
,
InputField
,
Inset
,
InteractiveTradingChart
,
Interpretation
,
Item
,
KagiChart
,
KaryTree
,
KirchhoffGraph
,
KnightTourGraph
,
Labeled
,
LabeledSlider
,
LayeredGraphPlot
,
LineBreakChart
,
LineGraph
,
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot
,
ListAnimate
,
ListContourPlot
,
ListContourPlot3D
,
ListCurvePathPlot
,
ListDensityPlot
,
ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot
,
ListLinePlot
,
ListLogLinearPlot
,
ListLogLogPlot
,
ListLogPlot
,
ListPicker
,
ListPlot
,
ListPlot3D
,
ListPointPlot3D
,
ListPolarPlot
,
ListStreamDensityPlot
,
ListStreamPlot
,
ListSurfacePlot3D
,
ListVectorDensityPlot
,
ListVectorPlot
,
ListVectorPlot3D
,
Locator
,
LocatorPane
,
LogLinearPlot
,
LogLogPlot
,
LogPlot
,
Manipulate
,
MatrixPlot
,
MenuView
,
MorphologicalGraph
,
Mouseover
,
NeighborhoodGraph
,
NicholsPlot
,
NyquistPlot
,
Opener
,
OpenerView
,
Overlay
,
PairedBarChart
,
PairedHistogram
,
PairedSmoothHistogram
,
Pane
,
Panel
,
PaneSelector
,
ParametricPlot
,
ParametricPlot3D
,
PasteButton
,
PathGraph
,
Periodogram
,
PetersenGraph
,
PieChart
,
PieChart3D
,
Plot
,
Plot3D
,
PointFigureChart
,
PolarPlot
,
Polygon
,
PopupMenu
,
PopupView
,
ProbabilityPlot
,
ProbabilityScalePlot
,
ProgressIndicator
,
QuantilePlot
,
RadioButton
,
RadioButtonBar
,
RandomGraph
,
RectangleChart
,
RectangleChart3D
,
RegionPlot
,
RegionPlot3D
,
ReliefPlot
,
RenkoChart
,
ReverseGraph
,
RevolutionPlot3D
,
RootLocusPlot
,
Rotate
,
Row
,
SectorChart
,
SectorChart3D
,
Setter
,
SetterBar
,
SimpleGraph
,
SingularValuePlot
,
Slider
,
Slider2D
,
SlideView
,
SmoothDensityHistogram
,
SmoothHistogram
,
SmoothHistogram3D
,
Spectrogram
,
SphericalPlot3D
,
StarGraph
,
StreamDensityPlot
,
StreamPlot
,
Subgraph
,
TabView
,
Text
,
ThermometerGauge
,
Toggler
,
TogglerBar
,
Tooltip
,
TradingChart
,
TreeForm
,
TreeGraph
,
TreePlot
,
Trigger
,
TuranGraph
,
UndirectedGraph
,
VectorDensityPlot
,
VectorPlot
,
VectorPlot3D
,
VerticalGauge
,
VerticalSlider
,
WaveletImagePlot
,
WaveletListPlot
,
WaveletMatrixPlot
,
WaveletScalogram
,
WeightedAdjacencyGraph
,
WheelGraph}];
```

Comment: It seems to me that the FontColor part is not working. Nothing is turning red running the code above. The rest does seem to work (different font size for example.) I am testing with a Plot and ListPlot. Any fix? (12.0.0 for Linux)

Comment: Is this supposed to affect the style for AxesLabel's? It seems it does not. How would I change the default color for those?

Comment: Change BaseStyle to LabelStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Just an oversized comment on the answer by Rolf Mertig.

The solution proposed there works but produces some errors. I think this is related to changing the default BaseStyle value for functions that don't take one.

With the following code I change both the default BaseStyle and the LabelStyle without errors. I simply take out the functions that produce an error compared to the answer by Rolf.

```
functionsThatDoNotAllowDefaultLabelStyle = {"ArrayPlot3D", 
   "AstroGraphics", "AxisObject", "BioSequencePlot", "BuckyballGraph",
    "Canvas", "ComplexArrayPlot", "ConcaveHullMesh", 
   "ConvexHullRegion", "CSGRegion", "CSGRegionTree", 
   "CumulativeFeatureImpactPlot", "DominatorTreeGraph", 
   "DualPlanarGraph", "ExpressionTree", "FeatureImpactPlot", 
   "FeatureValueDependencyPlot", "FeatureValueImpactPlot", 
   "FileSystemTree", "FindIsomorphicSubgraph", "GeoGraphPlot", 
   "GeoGraphValuePlot", "GradientFittedMesh", "GraphJoin", 
   "GraphProduct", "GraphSum", "GraphTree", "ImageVectorscopePlot", 
   "ImageWaveformPlot", "LayeredGraphPlot3D", "ListLinePlot3D", 
   "ListStreamPlot3D", "ListVectorDisplacementPlot", 
   "ListVectorDisplacementPlot3D", "NestTree", "ParallelAxisPlot", 
   "PointValuePlot", "RadialAxisPlot", "RandomTree", 
   "ReconstructionMesh", "RegionDilation", "RegionErosion", 
   "RootTree", "RulesTree", "StreamPlot3D", "TernaryListPlot", 
   "TorusGraph", "Tree", "UnlabeledTree", "VectorDisplacementPlot", 
   "VectorDisplacementPlot3D", "VertexInComponentGraph", 
   "VertexOutComponentGraph", "ArrayPlot3D", "AstroGraphics", 
   "AxisObject", "BioSequencePlot", "BuckyballGraph", "Canvas", 
   "ComplexArrayPlot", "ConcaveHullMesh", "ConvexHullRegion", 
   "CSGRegion", "CSGRegionTree", "CumulativeFeatureImpactPlot", 
   "DominatorTreeGraph", "DualPlanarGraph", "ExpressionTree", 
   "FeatureImpactPlot", "FeatureValueDependencyPlot", 
   "FeatureValueImpactPlot", "FileSystemTree", 
   "FindIsomorphicSubgraph", "GeoGraphPlot", "GeoGraphValuePlot", 
   "GradientFittedMesh", "GraphJoin", "GraphProduct", "GraphSum", 
   "GraphTree", "ImageVectorscopePlot", "ImageWaveformPlot", 
   "LayeredGraphPlot3D", "ListLinePlot3D", "ListStreamPlot3D", 
   "ListVectorDisplacementPlot", "ListVectorDisplacementPlot3D", 
   "NestTree", "ParallelAxisPlot", "PointValuePlot", "RadialAxisPlot",
    "RandomTree", "ReconstructionMesh", "RegionDilation", 
   "RegionErosion", "RootTree", "RulesTree", "StreamPlot3D", 
   "TernaryListPlot", "TorusGraph", "Tree", "UnlabeledTree", 
   "VectorDisplacementPlot", "VectorDisplacementPlot3D", 
   "VertexInComponentGraph", "VertexOutComponentGraph"};
functionsThatDoNotAllowDefaultBaseStyle = {"ArrayPlot3D", 
   "AstroGraphics", "AxisObject", "BioSequencePlot", "BuckyballGraph",
    "Canvas", "ComplexArrayPlot", "ConcaveHullMesh", 
   "ConvexHullRegion", "CSGRegion", "CSGRegionTree", 
   "CumulativeFeatureImpactPlot", "DominatorTreeGraph", 
   "DualPlanarGraph", "ExpressionTree", "FeatureImpactPlot", 
   "FeatureValueDependencyPlot", "FeatureValueImpactPlot", 
   "FileSystemTree", "FindIsomorphicSubgraph", "GeodesicPolyhedron", 
   "GeoGraphPlot", "GeoGraphValuePlot", "GradientFittedMesh", 
   "GraphJoin", "GraphProduct", "GraphSum", "GraphTree", 
   "ImageVectorscopePlot", "ImageWaveformPlot", "LayeredGraphPlot3D", 
   "ListLinePlot3D", "ListStreamPlot3D", "ListVectorDisplacementPlot",
    "ListVectorDisplacementPlot3D", "NestTree", "ParallelAxisPlot", 
   "PointValuePlot", "RadialAxisPlot", "RandomTree", 
   "ReconstructionMesh", "RegionDilation", "RegionErosion", 
   "RootTree", "RulesTree", "StreamPlot3D", "TernaryListPlot", 
   "TorusGraph", "Tree", "UnlabeledTree", "VectorDisplacementPlot", 
   "VectorDisplacementPlot3D", "VertexInComponentGraph", 
   "VertexOutComponentGraph"};

functionsPossiblyTakingDefaultLabelStyle = Select[
   Select[Names["System`*"], ! StringMatchQ[#, "*Box*" | "$*"] &],
   ! FreeQ[Options[Symbol[#]][[All, 1]], LabelStyle] &];

functionsTakingDefaultBaseStyle = Complement[
   Select[
    Select[Names["System`*"], ! StringMatchQ[#, "*Box*" | "$*"] &], ! 
      FreeQ[Options[Symbol[#]][[All, 1]], BaseStyle] &]
   , functionsThatDoNotAllowDefaultBaseStyle];

fnt = "16";
functionsTakingDefaultLabelStyle = 
  Complement[functionsPossiblyTakingDefaultLabelStyle, 
   functionsThatDoNotAllowDefaultLabelStyle];
initializationCommandDefaultStyles = 
  StringJoin[(StringJoin[
     "Map[SetOptions[#, LabelStyle \[Rule] \
{FontColor->Black,FontSize->" <> ToString[fnt] <> "}]&,\n{", 
     ExportString[
      Riffle[#, ","] &@
       ToExpression@Quiet@functionsTakingDefaultLabelStyle, "List"], 
     "}];\n"])
   , "\n",
   StringJoin[
    "Map[SetOptions[#, BaseStyle \[Rule] \
{FontColor->Black,FontSize->" <> ToString[fnt] <> "}]&,\n{", 
    ExportString[
     Riffle[#, ","] &@ToExpression@functionsTakingDefaultBaseStyle, 
     "List"], "}];\n"]
   ];
Export[FindFile["init.m"], initializationCommandDefaultStyles, "Text",
  CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"]

Get[$UserBaseDirectory <> "/Kernel/init.m"]
```