# Make equation size larger when using TraditionalForm

Tags: output, format

If I am using TraditionalForm, how do I make the output larger in size? I don't want to change the general font size of the GUI, just make the output of one expression larger. I tried:

```
TraditionalForm[x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3, FontSize -> Large]
```

but this does not work. FontSize is apparently not allowed as an attribute here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
Text[TraditionalForm[-1 + x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3], BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24}]
```

or equivalently

```
Text[TraditionalForm[-1 + x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3], BaseStyle -> {24}]
```

or

```
Text[TraditionalForm[-1 + x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3], BaseStyle -> {Large}]
```

The advantage of this version is that it can be `Print`ed and embedded inside any costructs like `Row`, `Grid` etc. without loosing the default appearance. Compare:

[image: screenshot]

Of course one can achieve the same with `Style`:

```
Print@TraditionalForm[Style[-1 + x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3, 24, FontFamily -> "Times"]]
```

Or even shorter using [built-in named styles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29527/280) defined in the Core.nb stylesheet:

```
Print@TraditionalForm[Style[-1 + x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3, "Graphics", 24]]
Print@TraditionalForm[Style[-1 + x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3, "TR", 24]]
```

The style `"Graphics"` is the default style for displaying `Graphics` (see detailed explanations [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36770/280)) and the `"TR"` style just sets the base font to be `"Times"` and `"Plain"` (i.e. "Times Regular"):

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "Of course we can achieve the same with Style but the Text - version is shorter:"  ...not really. `FontFamily->Times` is redundant as shown in my answer. The OP wants to change the appearance in his output, i.e. `Output` cell. You are printing stuff into `Print` cells which have completely different styling settings to `Output` cells ...hence your need to specify font family etc. which is unnecessary when rendering "proper" output.

Comment: @Mike You misunderstood my statement: it is related to the previous paragraph in my answer where I demonstrate that the default appearance is preserved with `Text` when it is `Print`ed and/or embedded in other constructs like `Row` or even `List`. From the other side, without `Text` the font is changed when `TraditionalForm` is `Print`ed. I use *Mathematica* 8.0.4.

Comment: If the OP had wanted to know how to preserve font family in various renderings, i.e. override default styles, then that would be relevant. But the question is about font size.

Comment: Yes, but why do not post additional way which has its own advantages (not related to the question but potentially useful to know). Your solution gives the standard and straightforward approach, mine is an alternative.

Comment: I have removed the statement that the `Text` solution is shorter since I have found even shorter ways to achieve the same with `Style` (see at the bottom of the answer).

Comment: In that case you should probably explain to the OP why "TR" and "Graphics" works. I know (short answer: see stylesheet) but new users probably don't.

Comment: Added explanations on the use of named styles.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `Style` whenever you want to change the style of something:

```
TraditionalForm[Style[x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3, FontSize -> 24]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

e.g.:

```
Magnify[TraditionalForm[x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3], 2]
```

*or*

```
TraditionalForm[Magnify[x^3 + y^3 == 22 z^3, 2]]
```

Depending on if you want to maintain TF.

Comment: Your first example doesn't answer the question. Of course the OP wants to maintain traditional form. That's what his question is all about.

Comment: @m_goldberg: TF might be interpreted only as the *order*, e.g. `-1+x` presented as `x-1`, or order and formatting. Hence both examples.

Comment: My objection stands.

Comment: @m_goldbergL Well, then downvote it if it makes you feel better.

Comment: No, it's not so great a sin as to warrant down-voting, but I would up-vote if you removed the first example.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Well, thanks for the indult, I guess. I think the first example is also useful, so zero-sum it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14391/discussion-between-m-goldberg-and-rasher)